# List Template issue on Sharepoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-calendar, list-template

I have an issue with the list template on Sharepoint Foundation 2013.
I've downloaded list as a template from SP 2007 (calendar is my template list in this situation). Done everything with .stp, .cab and back to .stp files and uploaded it to SPF2013 List templates. All is fine here.
THE ISSUE: I'm trying to add an app using that template and after a while trying to add it, SPF2013 throws me an error message "Unexpected error". The error message itself is blank - SPF2013 help window doesn't give me any info.
The only reason that I can think of for this to happen - there are more than 1000 entries in the calendar. However, I was able to import couple of calendars with more than 1000 entries no problem, it just suddenly stopped doing that for the next ones. 
My question is - does anyone know why the error occurs and the app can't be added based on the template? Is it due to the amount of the entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can't export a template from a previous version of SharePoint and expect it to work. You need to rebuild your template in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Well technically I agree and disagree with you.
I have multiple templates that I've exported from SP2007 (saved list / calendar as a template in .stp file) and migrated them onto SPF2013 using this information http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/09/migrating-sharepoint-2007-site-list-templates-to-sharepoint-2010.html
However, some specific templates simply doesn't load and I presume it's due to the size of it / contents.

Comment: Yeah, it's officially not supported to do so although there are hacks to work around it.

Comment: Thanks anyway, Trevor! After multiple templates worked for me this way - I would more expect it to work rather than not. So just thought there are some size limitations etc. It might be the structure of the lists / calendars, but it's weird when calendar with 1200 entries works perfectly fine and then calendar with 1248 entries doesn't..